# return IList but use List

Tags: c#, c#-2.0

Is it OK to to declare a return type of a method, e.g. IList that is less than you define it internally, e.g. List? Will it compile and run?

```
   protected static IList<String> GetJobFiles(String folder, String fileExtension)
    {
        List<String> jobFiles = new List<String>();

        if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(folder))
        {
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(folder, fileExtension);

            // Check if for matching files
            if (files.Length > 0)
            {
                // add the files to our list collection
                jobFiles.AddRange(files);
            }

        }

        return jobFiles;
    }
```

Comment: As Oded says this is fine and good practice, but you might even want to consider going an extra step and return IEnumerable.  Then if you want you can make this method use delayed execution by using yield.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `IList<string>` interface is implemented by both `List<string>` and `string[]`.

So you could return `jobFiles`, or, let's say down the road you decide that's not necessary and you want to just return `files` directly.

The fact that you've defined your method as returning an implementation of `IList<string>` rather than a `List<string>` allows you to do this **without affecting any external code***. This is in fact one of the *main purposes* of using interfaces.

<sub>*This is assuming you would not be treating the return value as a mutable collection using, e.g., `Add`, `Insert`, etc. Otherwise, you would in fact be affecting external code; but this is in theory at least one of the benefits of interfaces.</sub>

Answer (score 8):

This is not only fine, but good practice and the whole point of having interfaces as abstractions. See [`LSP`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) on wikipedia.

It allows you to use *any* implementer of `IList<T>` (so, not just `List<T>`, in case you want to change the internal implementation).

As for "will it compile and run" question - the answer is yes and yes, however, I encourage you to *try for yourself*. You will learn more and faster than posting here...

As @Dan Tao comments, try for yourself, but confirm (either here or with experienced colleagues).

Comment: +1 for trying it yourself, especially as it will be faster to type the above in an IDE than trying to get it into this forum.

Comment: Yes, *but* I would strongly *discourage* the mentality of "try for yourself rather than post on SO"; too many developers try for themselves, discover that something works, and henceforth treat it as a "magic trick." I think it's a great habit to seek the advice and guidance of a community whose members are likely to be knowledgeable on the subject.

Comment: ...so in other words, I'd say "try for yourself *in addition to* posting on SO" (not *instead of*).

Comment: @Dan Tao - I am a great believer in self discovery. I agree that one  should get guidance, however, one needs to start by trying to learn by themselves first.

Comment: @Oded: Yeah, I guess I just feel that in this case, the OP could've tried for himself and gotten the answer "yes, it will compile and run" without learning anything about whether it is a good practice or what the benefits are. This is where I believe there is value in asking others for more information.

Comment: @Dan Tao - fair point, and I agree with you to an extent. I would much rather see a "I tried this and don't understand _why_ it works. Can someone enlighten me" question than this one.

Answer (score 1):

Note that, depending on what the intended usage of the return value is, you might even choose to return IEnumerable:

```
protected static IEnumerable<String> GetJobFiles(String folder, String fileExtension)
```

This is even more general and you could use many types internally to build up the list (collection, queue, stack, or just an enumerator using yield) without impacting the caller.

In this case, the caller of the function can loop over the "job files", use the enumerable in linq (which he can also do with IList).

The caller cannot modify the list (he cannot add or remove files).

Answer (score 0):

Since IList is more "general" than List (in that List implements the IList interface), then this is a perfectly good way to do things.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's the purpose of an interface. You are specifying that something that implements the list interface will be returned. If you wanted to have several classes (Say Dog, Cat, Bird, etc) that all implemented IAnimal (Say had the Feed() and Bath() methods) you could have a function return an IAnimal without being specific as to which type of animal you'd get back.